# pytorch: zero_grad vs zero_grad() - role of parenthesis?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to train a pytorch model as follows:

```
start = time.time()

for epoch in range(100):

    t_loss = 0
    for i in range(100):


        optimizer.zero_grad
        scores = my_model(sent_dict_list[i])
        scores = scores.permute(0, 2, 1)

        loss = loss_function(scores, torch.tensor(targ_list[i]).cuda())
        t_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print("t_loss = ", t_loss)
```

I find that when I call "optimizer.zero_grad" my loss decreases at the end of every epoch whereas when I call "optimizer.zero_grad()" with the parenthesis it stays almost exactly the same. I don't know what difference this makes and was hoping someone could explain it to me.

Comment: optimizer.zero_grad is just a function name. you call the function with parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're new to python, the '()' means simple a function call. 
Consider this example:

```
>>> def foo():
       print("function")

>>> foo
<function __main__.foo>
>>> foo()
function
```

Remember functions are objects in python, you can even store them like this:

```
>>> [foo, foo, foo]
```

Returning to your question, you have to call the function otherwise it won't work.